# VPS Suddenly changed to Read only filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems

So I noticed my websites were showing 500 Internal server errors and when i try edit delete or add a file i get this error

```
rm: cannot remove `test': Read-only file system
```

I haven't updated or even logged into my server in a while so I don't think its anything I have done.

Has anyone any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Troubleshooting on your part? Is it in the VM alone, or the underlying system? Have you checked anything?

Comment: What should I test? Its a VPS, I dont have access to the underlying system.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to put `rm` and left off the first character. Then I'm guessing Linux. Start with the terminal and run `mount` and see if that lists your fs as read-only. If it does, remount it r/w. That should expose more info about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a physical server I would say the disk is failing. On a VPS there could be several underlying causes, but what it really means is that the kernel is receiving I/O errors in the disk subsystem.

**You should contact your provider to get the root cause fixed.**

You should also copy all essential data off of the VPS because you may be on the verge of losing it (but it's hard to say without knowing more details about the VPS underlying system).

Once you've copied your data off a reboot should bring the filesystem back to read/write. Be warned though, it might not be able to survive a reboot. It may be down hard if you try.

Again, contact your provider.